# Highsocre to text file

Tags: java, text-files

I'm trying to write a high score for my program to a text file. I have this code and it is working;

```
if(gameOver == true){
        int highscore = score;
    String username = "Jay";



    try {

        String content = username;

        File file = new File("highscore.txt");



        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(f);
        b.write(content + "\t" + "Score: " + highscore);

        b.close();

        System.out.println("Score Saved");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

But every time I restart the game the high score gets overridden. How would I make it so that it writes to the next line and is there a way to sort it by highest score?

Thanks
Jay

Comment: modify your `FileWriter` like `new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true)`. This will set him into append-mode

Comment: @Jay.. try this FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);

Comment: To append, you have to open it in append mode. But if you want to sort by highest score anyway, you should first read out all the data in it, then add the newest highscore, sort that datastructure (or use a sorting one in the first place) and write it back to file. Note: you better put a limit on how many scores you want to "remember".

Comment: You need to explore more JAVA IO API.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileWriter constructor with append parameter:

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

And you must call append method instead of write:

```
b.append(content).append("\t").append("Score: " + highscore);
```